# Toolbar doesn't hide completely on scroll

Tags: scroll, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I try to hide the toolbar during scroll but then this happens! What do I have to do?

This is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/SimpleTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/SimpleTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The view container has following behavior:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**Screenshots:
[Before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeLTu.png)
[After scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAMBb.png)**

Comment: Did you use `windowDrawSystemBackgrounds` in your theme?

Answer (score 9):

There is something with 'fitsSystemWindows'
Make it false in coordinatorLayout and true in AppBarLayout

Comment: this partially works, but somehow I loose the statusbar's colorPrimaryDark effect

Comment: Great. Works. Why is not this accepted answer? @Jan-LkElse

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!